# iPad views "frame"

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview

I'm trying to make an application which splits the screen into 3 separate parts as shown by the image below with the blue section changing frequently, the green having static data and the red section changing rarely but independently from the blue section.

What is the best way to set this up?

[image: iPad View]

Comment: u mean like in a UISplitViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is to create 3 views. Create them in Interface Builder with the dimensions you need.

Synthesize them & manipulate these views from your code... You need not have 3 separate viewControllers. You could manage them all from one single viewController.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Apple provides developers with a controller class specifically for managing split views; now, as far as if that's simply 2 views beside each other or not I don't know. However, you could make the green/blue view the views managed by this controller object and have the red view be independent.